# VK Token генерация сообщений в html

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

Помогите пожалуйста сделать генерацию сообщений в html, не знаю как сделать саму генерацию в js, токен подключен, method тоже, заранее огромное спасибо! =)

Comment: А можно пример сообщения или описание? Потому-что словосочетание [генерация сообщений в html], имеет достаточно обширное понятие...